# What happens if I map a drive multiple times?

Tags: windows, c#, network-drive

I have a drive mapping function called `MapDrive` which takes the necessary information to map a network drive (path, drive letter, user/pass). What happens if my code calls this function multiple times with the same parameters? As in, I map the same drive more than once during the same session.

NOTE: I have ran this multiple times and each time nothing happens (same drive letter, same everything). I am asking if there is something happening that just isn't showing up as an error (i.e. performance issues, ect...)

```
public static void MapDrive(string DriveLetter, string UNCPath, string strUsername, string strPassword)
    {
        try
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "net.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = " use " + DriveLetter + ": " + UNCPath + " " + strPassword + " /USER:" + strUsername;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handle exception
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing much happens. If you run a batch file to map a drive it will just return an error that the drive letter has already been mapped. On the other hand, you can map the same network location to different drive letters.

You might experience performance issues if your computer has difficulty reaching the network location or the network speed is slower. There are a variety of factors that would influence this. Most likely, the performance decrease is neglible. Just don't start looping this.